# Comparing Entity Images between AD and CRM 2016

Tags: .net, active-directory, dynamics-crm

I want to add and update contact pictures of our Active Directory users who are saved in CRM contacts as well, based on pictures I find in the AD.

This already works very well but I don't know how to find out if there's a difference in the pictures after CRM has saved it.

Even if I convert all AD images to 144x144 jpg byte[] and overwrite what I've got in CRM, the next sync reports a difference for all contacts and therefore re-updates them. Which still works fine but generates unwanted audit history entries of course.

I use a data sync tool for the sync itself which uses the SDK so I don't have the complete mastery over what happens in CRM.

Anybody who knows if CRM does some more "magic" than resizing to 144x144 when saving entityimages? Does CRM convert do a specific format (JPG etc) or does it just leave the orginal file format intact?

Comment: I believe the image is stored as a Base64-encoded string, it could be an Encoding issue (UTF8 vs Unicode vs ...). I'm not familiar enough with entityimages to have a more accurate hypothesis.

Comment: How are you comparing the images?

Comment: tried to just compare != byte[] of resized image from AD/Office 365 to CRM's entityimage field

Comment: @Alex Entity images are stored in an "image" type field in SQL server which is depreciated, API returns Byte[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** 
A few things I found out & my workaround:

- CRM is storing a jpg/jfif in the table ImageDescriptor
- CRM resizes all incoming images to 144x144, no large orginal etc remains.
- You can check the size in SQL using select DATALENGTH(ImageData) from ImageDescriptor where ObjectId = 'XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX'(where xxxx is the contactid of your contact)
- If you open a contact in the CRM UI and save picture, it has the very same size as the database reports - so: no magic here.
- Before syncing the AD picture to CRM I am converting to JPEG and resize to 144x144 but still for some images my result size is 2bytes different, while 99% of the pictures work. The approach to convert them first, then compare them seems to be good, but needs more investigation about compression etc. which makes the tiny difference (which on the fist view is the very same btw)
- Another reason for the randomly different file sizes could be that applying a jpeg compression to a file (which I do for the AD source images) could not be deterministic and/or CRM's own "inbound conversion" to jpg could alter the filesize at the time of saving it to CRM (even the inbound file has the very same dimensions and compression level as the target format of CRM)
- My workaround is to compare the size of the original picture with a custom entity field stored at the conact which I set after each sync. This should work in the cases.

Thanks for your previous comments, will close this entry since workaround works fine.

Comment: My workaround will be changed to not compare file size but hashes for the orginal file which is more precise